# How can I have the table headers repeat throughout the view results for every X results?

Tags: views

I have a view that has a lot of columns with numbers in it and about 200 records in it.  As I view the results and scroll down, I forget what each column's title is.  Is there a module or other way to have views include the table headers ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the display style type of table in your view, you can set the checkbox for: *Enable Drupal style "sticky" table headers (Javascript)*

This will freeze the headers and allow the table data to scroll.